# SoapUI not finding my wsdl: fail to load url

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

Following is wsdl code

while I use it for analysis it give me error of prototype can you help

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.8 svn-revision#13980. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service.vep.mbca.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://service.vep.mbca.com/" name="ProcessCreditDecisionServiceService">
<import namespace="http://iservice.vep.mbca.com/" location="https://localhost:443/vepapi/web-service/mbfs/processCreditDecision?wsdl=1"/>
<binding xmlns:ns1="http://iservice.vep.mbca.com/" name="ProcessCreditDecisionServicePortBinding" type="ns1:IProcessCreditDecisionService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="processCreditDecision">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>

</binding>

<service name="ProcessCreditDecisionServiceService">
<port name="ProcessCreditDecisionServicePort" binding="tns:ProcessCreditDecisionServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://localhost:443/vepapi/web-service/mbfs/processCreditDecision"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSDL issues happen in SOAP UI sometimes when the end-points you are trying  to hit is either not active or does not exist.

```
<soap:address location="https://localhost:443/vepapi/web-service/mbfs/processCreditDecision"/>
```

1. Perform schema validation once, check whether you are abiding to the rules. In specific, check the binding part.
2. Cross validate the end point you are pointing in the soap request and the one in the wsdl.

check the endpoints.